# Orchard CMS OrchardSuppressDependency not working

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, suppress

I'm trying to replace the Orchard CMS `NavigationManager` in `Orchard.UI.Navigation` so I can filter menu items based on permissions. Here is my code:

```
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.UI.Navigation.NavigationManager")]
public class MmtNavigationManager : NavigationManager
{

    public MmtNavigationManager(IEnumerable<INavigationProvider> providers, IAuthorizationService authorizationService, UrlHelper urlHelper, IOrchardServices orchardServices)
    : base(providers, authorizationService, urlHelper, orchardServices)
    {

    }

    public new IEnumerable<MenuItem> BuildMenu(string menuName)
    {
        var menu = base.BuildMenu(menuName);
        return menu;
    }
}
```

This code is in an installed and enabled module. The constructor gets called but never the `BuildMenu` method; The origional `BuildMenu` gets called instead.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, sussed it out. I needed to make my new class (`MmtNavigationManager`) Inherit from `INavigationManager` as well.